# File Inbound Adapter example provided in sample not working

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class FileReadingJavaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(FileReadingJavaApplication.class)
            .web(false)
            .run(args);
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow fileReadingFlow() {
         return IntegrationFlows
                  .from(s -> s.file(new File(INBOUND_PATH))
                              .patternFilter("*.txt"),
                          e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(1000)))
                  .transform(Files.toStringTransformer())
                  .channel("processFileChannel")
                  .get();
        }

}
```

Reads following error in eclipse: 
Multiple markers at this line
    - The target type of this expression must be a functional interface
    - The method from(String, boolean) in the type IntegrationFlows is not applicable for the arguments (( s) -> {}, ( e) -> {})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you use Spring Integration 5.x already. There is no that factory for channel Adapters to avoid cyclic dependency. You need to use `Files.inboundAdaper()` instead of that first lambda.

See the migration guide: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/wiki/Spring-Integration-4.3-to-5.0-Migration-Guide

Also, please, raise an issue on GitHub to fix that sample in the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.1.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/files.html#_configuring_with_the_java_dsl_8

See a sample configuration in the test case: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-file/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/file/dsl/FileTests.java

Plus you can find some of them in the samples: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples

Comment: Has been fixed with this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/commit/4c6ffec6fe85fb11707749725964d1a6d1d3e1ff